# Kafka streams: Is there a way to delete an entry from kv store only if successfully committed to topics?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka streams, my kv store is linked to a sink which sends records to output topic.
- What exceptions would we get if for some reason sink can't commit records to topics?

Answer (score 0):

If the sink cannot write the record it will internally retry and after all retries are exhausted the whole application goes down with an exception. If the store was updated successfully it will (by default only) contain the data and you cannot delete it. This is the guarantee "at-least-once" processing gives you.

As of Kafka 0.11 you can enable "exactly-once" processing:

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

For this case, on application restart the store will be deleted and recreated before any processing is repeated. This ensures, that the data written to the store before the error will be "removed" before processing continues.